# can my Qt Application get Mac look on windows

Tags: qt

As Qt application will be in native look and feel. 
I want to get mac look and feel for my Qt application. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: what is there to down vote

Comment: I didn't downvoted, but I think that downvotes are given, because you didn't read Qt documentation, before asking such questions. There are everything clear.

Comment: Agree - if you read documentation and try to make your own code, you will probably receive the answer yourself

Comment: I googled it and could not find right answer any where. and I thought of searching in a qt documentation but I have no clue with what term/keyword I have to search for, so finally came here. hope its clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to change look and feel of Qt application by using styles:

```
QApplication::setStyle("macintosh");
```

List of available styles is given by:

```
QStringList list = QStyleFactory::keys();
```

But for example on Windows Mac style is typically unavailable. I tested on Windows machine with Qt 5.4 - only Windows (Windows, WindowsXP and WindowsVista) and Fusion styles are available - you can switch between them.

Of course, Windows style is default for Windows. It is advised to set style before constructing QApplication.

Comment: Because "Windows Vista+" and "OS X" styles are using platform-depend API for drawing controls.